# Share data between different msbuild inline tasks

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-4.0

I would like to create two custom inline tasks that share some data.
For example, one task sets a global variable and the other one reads it.
Is there some common context in which both tasks are compiled where I could place the common data?
(btw I know I can do it in non-inline task, the question is specific to inline tasks)

A possible solution is to create just one inline task with a parameter that specifies which "function" to run, much like `TaskAction` property in MSBuild Extension Pack. But is there a way to do that with two separate inline tasks?

Comment: If I understood you correctly - you should use MSBuild properties / items to share state, not static variables.

Comment: well the shared data is used internally between these two tasks, it should not be visible to the task user. I don't want the caller of these tasks to repeatedly pass on this data between these tasks.